# How to remove all characters after first space for OLAP dimension members

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

I have a dimension that consists of members with the following format 100 - Sales, 200 - Purchase etc. What I wish to do, is to substring starting from the left and remove everyting after the first space. So the result would be "100" and "200" for the two examples. I have done this in sql before with the following code syntax:
LEFT(MyField, CHARINDEX('', MyField) - 1)

But it doesnt seem to work when I apply the same logic in SSAS.
LEFT([MyField].[MyField].Members,CHARINDEX('',[MyField].[MyField].Members)-1).

Does anyone know the syntax to accomplish the same thing in SSAS?

Best regards,
Rubrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [INSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/instr-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15) function (instead of CHARINDEX), so something like this on Adventure Works database:

```
with member Measures.[Short Name]
as
left("Aaron A. Allen", instr("Aaron A. Allen", " " ) - 1)

select Measures.[Short Name] on 0,
[Customer].[Customer].members on 1
from [Adventure Works];
```

or like this:

```
with member Measures.[Customer Short Name]
as
left([Customer].[Customer].currentmember.MEMBER_CAPTION, instr([Customer].[Customer].currentmember.MEMBER_CAPTION, " " ) - 1)

select {Measures.[Customer Short Name], [Measures].[Customer Count]} on 0,
[Customer].[Customer].members on 1
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]